# Neo4j Enterprise 3.0 fails to start

Tags: neo4j, java-8

I have installed a fresh version of Neo4j 3.0 enterprise on ubuntu 14.04. Also installed java 8..

After rebooting the server I see that neo4j is running in processes but if I do `#service neo4j status` I get `neo4j is not running`

it seems like neo4j is already running but not from the same init.d neo4j script.

When I run `#service neo4j start` I get

```
Starting Neo4j.
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 149: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory
```

Log from neo4j:

```
2016-05-05 09:51:57.905+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-05-05 09:51:58.856+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-05-05 09:51:58.875+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2016-05-05 09:51:59.006+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@36b36a23' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@36b36a23' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@36b36a23' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:81)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@36b36a23' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.EnterpriseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.EnterpriseFacadeFactory.newFacade(EnterpriseFacadeFactory.java:42)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:85)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@130ceaaa' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.storeLockException(StoreLocker.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        ... 12 more
```

Java version installed:

java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Any suggestions? I tried to install twice and I get the same problem..

Please help :)

Comment: Try remove `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock` file and restart `neo4j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.. neo4j install process did not created a directory for pid in /var/run/
Created manually and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check for running java processes using `jps` or `ps aux | grep java`. Make sure no process is running for the given db location.